# Change color of selected NSTabView Tab for OS X App

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, tabs, nstabview

I'm working on an OS X application with Xcode and swift, and I am trying to get the color of the clicked NSTabView to change from it's default blue color. I can't seem to find much information on this, and when I do it is really old. It seems like it is much easier to make changes with iOS, but I specifically need changes on my OS X App in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do it within Interface Builder?

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not find a way to do this, and after a lot of research I couldn't find that anyone else found a way either.

Answer (score 0):

I have done that by changing the colour of window where I am switching from one tab to other.
    [windowMain setBackgroundColor:[NSColor grayColor]];
or any colour.

Comment: Thanks for responding Sahil. I've mostly done my changes in storyboard. Where would I implement this code exactly?

Comment: you can implement this statement next to the statement where you going from one tab to other.